# Modifying django object model for better admin CRUD management

Tags: django

I am writing a blog app using django 1.10

This is a snippet of my object model:

**model.py**

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='attachments')


class FileAttachments(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField(Attachment)    


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    file_attachments = models.ForeignKey(FileAttachments, blank=True, null=True)    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, default='', unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/blog/%s/%s/%s/%s/" % (self.pub_date.year, self.pub_date.month, self.pub_date.day, self.slug)   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Posts"
        ordering = ["-create_date"]

        permissions = ( 
            ( "create", "Create Post" ),
            ( "modify", "Modify Post" ),
            ( "delete", "Delete Post" ),
        )
```

**(simplified) admin.py:**

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    exclude = ('author',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

when I try to access the Post object via the admin page - in the list view, I only see 'Post object' - whereas I want to see the title of the post (and possibly, a few other attributes of the Post object) - how do I modify the admin view to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem - you need to define [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in your `PostAdmin`, like that:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    exclude = ('author',)
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')
```

As for your second problem - please stick to the 'One post, one problem' rule; hint - `ForeignKey` means only one FileAttachment can be related to your Post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `__unicode__` for `__str__` in your Post class and print whatever you want.  For example: `return "Blog %s published on %s" %(self.title, self.pub_date)`.
2. Your Post model only includes one attachment through a foreign key.  That way it will be impossible to upload more than one file.  In other words, you have to change your models, for example including a key in FileAttachments relating to a Post and removing the key from Post model.

Hope this helps.